# How to change the css for a label?

Tags: css, css-selectors

how do I change the opacity of a checked label?

```css
label {
opacity:.5;
}
input[name="myname"]:checked + label {
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-input">
<input type="radio" id="myid1" name="myname" />
<input type="radio" id="myid2" name="myname" />
<input type="radio" id="myid3" name="myname" />
</div>
<div class="my-label">
<label for="myid1">content label 1</label>
<label for="myid2">content label 2</label>
<label for="myid3">content label 3</label>
</div>
```

how to change this code?

```
input[name="myname"]:checked + label
```

I changed this:

```
input[name="myname"]:checked > label
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build? Is your HTML structure fixed?

Comment: I can not change the html structure.
I have to stay that way.

Comment: Well, changing to `input[name="myname"]:checked > label` won't work as it will be explicit child element and label is not child of input. Have you tried `~` sibling selector ?

Comment: How to use javascript?

Comment: This question should be opened up. Its not a duplicate, the solution of the 'duplicate' question does not work.

Comment: It _is_ a duplicate, in that the referred thread explains why what gets demanded here is _not possible_ - not with that HTML structure. And if the HTML structure can not be changed, then that vital information should have been included in the question to begin with, and not only mentioned in a comment on an answer for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your HTML to this:

```css
label {
  opacity: .5;
}

input[name="myname"]:checked+label {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-item">
  <input type="radio" id="myid1" name="myname" />
  <label for="myid1">content label 1</label>
</div>

<div class="radio-item">
  <input type="radio" id="myid2" name="myname" />
  <label for="myid2">content label 2</label>
</div>

<div class="radio-item">
  <input type="radio" id="myid3" name="myname" />
  <label for="myid3">content label 3</label>
</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio for more information about radio items.

If you can't change your HTML structure then JavaScript is the way to go.

```js
var id;

$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e) {
  // Find the selected radio item and store the id
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  
  // Reset the labels
  $('label').removeClass('active');
  
  // Set active state on the correct label based on the id
  $('label[for="' + id + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
label {
  opacity:.5;
}
label.active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-input">
  <input type="radio" id="myid1" name="myname" />
  <input type="radio" id="myid2" name="myname" />
  <input type="radio" id="myid3" name="myname" />
</div>
<div class="my-label">
  <label for="myid1">content label 1</label>
  <label for="myid2">content label 2</label>
  <label for="myid3">content label 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not change the html structure!

Comment: Just a small typo: ur 3rd radio is calling myid2, should be calling myid3

Comment: @Mahdi can you explain why your HTML can't change? Maybe there is a way to create your lay-out with my HTML and some extra CSS?

Comment: If you change the html structure, the display mode changes

Comment: @Mahdi here you have an example I fastly created with my HTML and some extra CSS so you have your first lay-out https://jsfiddle.net/arh1ngtk/
It's not the most dynamic code I know but maybe gives this an idea that there is a way to do this without JavaScript?

If you like to do this with JavaScript then you can do this with a click event and use the id of the input field to find the related label.

Comment: @Nick_Van_Loocke Can you give JavaScript example code?

Comment: @Mahdi I've explained it in my answer or you can also view it on https://jsfiddle.net/arh1ngtk/1/